# Pointwise boundedness of continuous functions on a complete metric space implies uniform boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I am in the process of proving the following:

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of continuous real-valued functions on a complete metric space $X$ that is pointwise bounded in the sense that for each $x \in X$, there is a constant $M_{x}$ for which $|f(x)|\leq M_{x}$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$.
>
> Then, there is a nonempty open subset $\mathcal{O}$ of $X$ on which $F$ is uniformly bounded in the sense that there is a constant $M$ for which $|f|\leq M$ on $\mathcal{O}$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$.

So far, I have done the following:

> Define the sets $E_{n} = \{ x \in X: |f(x)|\leq n, \forall f \in \mathcal{F}\} = \cap_{f \in \mathcal{F}}\{x \in X: |f(x)|\leq n\} = \cap_{f \in \mathcal{F}}f^{-1}[-n,n]$, which is closed in $X$, since $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of continuous functions.
>
> Since $\mathcal{F}$ is pointwise bounded, then $\exists x \in E_{n}$ whenever $|f(x)|\leq M_{x} \leq n$, which implies that $X = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$.
>
> Since $X$ is nonempty, it has nonempty interior, and since $X = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$, by a previous result, at least one of the $E_{n}$'s, say $E_{n_{0}}$ has nonempty interior; i.e., for $x_{0} \in E_{n_{0}}$, $\exists r>0$ such that $B_{0}(x_{0},r)\subset E_{n_{0}}=\overline{E_{n_{0}}}$.

From here, I have no idea where to go in order to get the uniform boundedness. Please help. I am completely and utterly clueless as to how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have any guess for what $\mathcal{O}$ might be?

Comment: @EricWofsey, is it $B_{0}(x_{0},r)$? And if not that particular ball, a ball like it?

Comment: If $\mathcal{O}=B_0(x_0,r)$, what would you guess $M$ would be?  Can you try and prove that your guess works?

Comment: @EricWofsey, not a clue, honestly.

Comment: Do you know of _any_ set on which $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded?

Comment: You basically are done. You just have to pick up the pieces and tie them together. Read the last sentence in the problem statement, and the last sentence in "I have done the following". Take a look at both, and try to see that what you have is what you want.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I must admit that after this point, I have gone looking for solutions online for what to do next, and some of what I have seen has some weird stuff going on involving $\Vert x \Vert$ that I don't understand at all. Especially since $\Vert x \Vert$ should not appear in uniform bound. Is it $r$ that I'm supposed to be bounding it by?

Comment: How do **at least one of the $E_n$'s, say $E_{n_0}$ has nonempty interior** and **there is a nonempty open subset $\mathcal{O}$ of $X$** tie together?

Comment: @DanielFischer, the other guy asked me the same thing. I said $B_{0}(x_{0},r)$ would be the $\mathcal{O}$ in that situation, but then I didn't know what $M$ would be, and I've been lost ever since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are done. All that remains is that you recognise that you are done, and sum it up in a concluding sentence.

You have defined

$$E_n = \bigcap_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f^{-1}([-n,n]),$$

so directly by definition, the family $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded on each $E_n$ - and on all subsets of $E_n$ - with a uniform bound of $n$, any $M \geqslant n$ is a fortiori a uniform bound of $\mathcal{F}$ on a subset of $E_n$.

You have used Baire's theorem to conclude

> at least one of the $E_n$'s, say $E_{n_0}$ has nonempty interior;

so that means $\overset{\Large\circ}{E}_{n_0}$, or $\operatorname{int}(E_{n_0})$, or whatever your preferred notation is, **is a nonempty open subset of $X$**.

And since $\overset{\Large\circ}{E}_{n_0}$ is a subset of $E_{n_0}$, we know that $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded by $n_0$ on $\overset{\Large\circ}{E}_{n_0}$.

So we can take $\mathcal{O} = \overset{\Large\circ}{E}_{n_0}$ and $M = n_0$.

We can also take any nonempty open subset of $\overset{\Large\circ}{E}_{n_0}$ and any $M \geqslant n_0$.

Or, since we have the inclusion $E_n \subseteq E_{n+1}$ for all $n$, it follows that if $\overset{\Large\circ}{E}_{n_0} \neq \varnothing$, then $\overset{\Large\circ}{E}_{n} \neq \varnothing$ for all $n \geqslant n_0$, so we can take a nonempty open subset of $E_{n_1}$ for some $n_1 > n_0$ and an $M \geqslant M_1$. We have lots of options to choose from.